# R Shiny: Adding to plot via a loop

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create an app that displays an animation of sampling means using Shiny. Something similar to the example shown [here](http://onlinestatbook.com/stat_sim/sampling_dist/).

Here's some minimal code showing just the section I'm having trouble with. This is not the data I'm using, but a reproducible example data set.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(ID=1:60, 
                   x=sort(runif(n = 60)), 
                   y=sort(runif(n = 60)+rnorm(60)))

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("n",
                    "Number of samples:",
                    min = 10,
                    max = 100,
                    value = 20),

        sliderInput("surveys",
                    "Number of surveys:",
                    min = 10,
                    max = 100,
                    value = 20),

        checkboxInput("replacement", 
                      "Sample with replacement?"),

        actionButton("button", "Go!")
    ),
    # Show the plot
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput("plot1")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        plot1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(colour="red") + theme_bw()
        plot1 <- plot1 + geom_vline(xintercept = mean(data$x), size=1.1, colour="red")
        plot1

        for(i in 1:20){
            data$sampled <- "red"
            sample.rows <- sample(data$ID, 20, replace = F)
            data$sampled[sample.rows] <- "green"

            plot1 <- plot1 + geom_point(x=data$x, y=data$y, colour=data$sampled, size=2)

            sample.mean.x <- mean(data$x[sample.rows])

            plot1 <- plot1 + geom_vline(xintercept = sample.mean.x, colour="green")

            print(plot1)
            Sys.sleep(1.5)
        }
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The part within `renderPlot({ ... })` does exactly what I want when pasted into the console, but how do I get this to happen in Shiny? Ideally, I would also like the plot to appear first, and then the animation (green bars) to start when the `actionButton` is clicked.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647828/how-can-i-build-shiny-applications-with-animation-in-r. Your strategy isn't going to work because nothing will update till the function returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reactiveTimer` to do that. I have modified the server part of your code. In the code below I have set the timer for two seconds so that the plot updates every two seconds.

```
  server <- function(input, output) {

    autoInvalidate <- reactiveTimer(2000)
    plot1 <- NULL

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
      plot1 <<- ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(colour="red") + theme_bw()
      plot1 <<- plot1 + geom_vline(xintercept = mean(data$x), size=1.1, colour="red")
      plot1
    })

    observeEvent(input$button,{

      output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
        autoInvalidate()
        data$sampled <- "red"
        sample.rows <- sample(data$ID, 20, replace = F)
        data$sampled[sample.rows] <- "green"

        plot1 <<- plot1 + geom_point(x=data$x, y=data$y, colour=data$sampled, size=2)

        sample.mean.x <- mean(data$x[sample.rows])

        plot1 <<- plot1 + geom_vline(xintercept = sample.mean.x, colour="green")

        plot1

      })
    })
  }
```

**[EDIT]**:

As you wanted the loop to be run only 20 times I have modified the code with the help of the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43251477/5894457) link so that the reactive timer is run only till the count is 20. Here is the code that you need to add from the link:

```
  invalidateLaterNew <- function (millis, session = getDefaultReactiveDomain(), update = TRUE) 
  {
    if(update){
      ctx <- shiny:::.getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext()
      shiny:::timerCallbacks$schedule(millis, function() {
        if (!is.null(session) && session$isClosed()) {
          return(invisible())
        }
        ctx$invalidate()
      })
      invisible()
    }
  }

  unlockBinding("invalidateLater", as.environment("package:shiny"))
  assign("invalidateLater", invalidateLaterNew, "package:shiny")
```

Here is the server code for it:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

count = 0
plot1 <- NULL


  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot1 <<- ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(colour="red") + theme_bw()
    plot1 <<- plot1 + geom_vline(xintercept = mean(data$x), size=1.1, colour="red")
    plot1
  })

observeEvent(input$button,{
 count <<- 0
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    count <<- count+1
    invalidateLater(1500, session,  count < 20)
    data$sampled <- "red"
    sample.rows <- sample(data$ID, 20, replace = F)
    data$sampled[sample.rows] <- "green"

    plot1 <<- plot1 + geom_point(x=data$x, y=data$y, colour=data$sampled, size=2)

    sample.mean.x <- mean(data$x[sample.rows])

    plot1 <<- plot1 + geom_vline(xintercept = sample.mean.x, colour="green")

    plot1

  })
})


 }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! Just a follow-up: Where do I put the second code block (i.e. the first block after your edit)?

Comment: Never mind, worked that bit out. How do I get the plot to display first though? In the first version (without the 20 limit), it displays the plot first, but won't loop until the Go! button is pressed. Second version won't display the plot first though...

Comment: Worked that out too ;)  
Had to move the `observeEvent(input$button,{` to before the second `renderPlot({` call.

Comment: You are right, but you need to put ` count <<- 0` inside the `observeEvent` of the `actionButton` so that the counter resets every time you click the button.

Comment: One problem you might encounter if you move that ` renderPlot` outside the `observeEvent` of `input$button` is clearing the plot to render new plot. So, for those cases you may want to leave the  renderPlot` inside the `observeEvent`.

Comment: I have encountered the problem you predicted! Any ideas on how to have it both ways? I.e. display the plot on first run, but then be able to reset (with a button)? I've asked it as a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43383010/r-shiny-reset-plot-to-default-state).

Comment: One way to do it would be adding `plot1<<-NULL` inside the `observeEvent` and then add the copy the initial `renderPlot`  after that. There must be more elegant ways to do it but this should work too. Will edit the answer with this later when I am on my PC. Hope this solves the issue.